# Matrix indexing combinations but one per row

Tags: python

I am after extracting data from an n*m matrix to accumulate the value for unique row combinations

Imagine

```
[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I would be after the indexes to produce

1+4+7

1+4+8

1+4+9

2+4+7

2+4+9

...

I have looked over itertools as well as numpy but I am unable to realise a means to pull the combination

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itertools has it:

```
import itertools
x = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for y in list(itertools.product(*x)):
   print y
```

it gives you:

```
(1, 4, 7)
(1, 4, 8)
(1, 4, 9)
(1, 5, 7)
(1, 5, 8)
(1, 5, 9)
(1, 6, 7)
...
(3, 6, 9)
```

Comment: Ok the is really odd. I was going over that exact function and for some reason I was not convinced it would work. Let me recheck my use case and if so I'll accept this

Comment: Just a tip, `list` is not needed. `product` returns an iterable and turning it into a list will be very slow for larger matrices

Comment: right so the reason I didn't think this would work is I have a number of these matrixes (same dimentions) and I need to compare such combinatorial accumulations. If product iterates through in a predictable way (ie the logical manner) then yes this should work as I can execute this on each matrix, sum the resultant list and then compare the resultant lists